# Update Password in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, passwords

I am creating login application (Windows Forms) in C# and using .NET Framework 4.5 with Visual Studio 2012.

I have already entered username and password into database manually.

So in **LoginForm**, where user enter their username and password my code is like:

```
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection con;
    System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds1;
    int MaxRows = 0;
    int inc = 0;

    private void go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Users"].Rows[inc];
        if (EnterMasterPassword.Text == dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString())
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Try again");
    }

    private void LoginForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\\PMDatabase.sdf";
        con.Open();
        ds1 = new DataSet();
        string sql = "SELECT * From tbl_login";
        da = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds1, "Users");
        MaxRows = ds1.Tables["Users"].Rows.Count;
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

*where *go* is an button*

This works perfectly and users login successfully. But I have no idea how to provide an update/change password functionality to user using Windows Forms. How to update database? And username and password field in it?

**So far I have done following procedure:**

When user clicks on *"Update Password" button* a new form **(name: Form7)** opens which has 3 labels, 3 text-boxes and one button- namely:-

TextBox1--> CurrentPassword

TextBox2--> NewPassword

TextBox3--> ConfirmNewPassword

Button--> UpdateUsrPassword

the code for Form7 is like:-

```
public partial class Form7 : Form
    {
        public PasswordsAndData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection con1;
        System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter da1;
        DataSet ds2;
        int totalPasswords = 0, inc = 0;
        private void Form7_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con1 = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection();
            con1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\\PMDatabase.sdf";
            con1.Open();
            ds2 = new DataSet();
            string sql = "SELECT * From tbl_UserData";
            da1 = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, con1);
            da1.Fill(ds2, "UserData");
            totalPasswords = ds2.Tables["UserData"].Rows.Count;
            con1.Close();
        }
        private void UpdateUsrPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(NewPassword.Text == ConfirmNewPassword.Text)
            {
                DataRow dRow1 = ds2.Tables["UserData"].NewRow();
                dRow1[1] = ConfirmNewPassword.Text;            
                ds2.Tables["UserData"].Rows.Add(dRow1);
                UpdateDB();
                MessageBox.Show("Password Updated");
                totalPasswords++;
                inc = totalPasswords - 1;
            }
        }
        private void UpdateDB()
        {
            System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommandBuilder cb1;
            cb1 = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommandBuilder(da1);
            cb1.DataAdapter.Update(ds2.Tables["UserData"]);
        }
    }
```

But the above code is not updating the password. How to correct above code? So its works perfectly.

Please guide me.

Comment: Side note: You'll get negative score on your assignment if you continue saving passwords in plain text into DB.

Comment: Did you get any errors when you run the above code? please show the Error

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov Encrypting password and save to database is not a must

Comment: You are *Adding* a row.. should you instead *update* the row?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Probably not just for storing passwords in plaintext but for having database access in Form Code-Behind as well :P

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow dRow1 = ds2.Tables["UserData"].NewRow();
dRow1[1] = ConfirmNewPassword.Text;            
ds2.Tables["UserData"].Rows.Add(dRow1);
UpdateDB();
```

You are adding a row in your `UpdateUsrPassword_Click` but shouldn't you instead updating the existing row?

You should do:

1. Get actual password from db
2. UPDATE of the existing row containing the actual password

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding a row you should use something like this:

```
dataSet1.Tables["Customers"].Rows[4]["CompanyName"] = "Updated Company Name";
```

this updates the value in the dataset, which you can then push back to the database.

source with more info on editing values in a dataset:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc.aspx